# Drawing Rectangles using a starting and ending point C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas

In WP7, the drawing of the rectangle takes place from top that is the origin part.

Can I do something such as, create a starting point and ending point and then draw customised rectangles into it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Canvas and position the Rectangle within the Canvas using the following :-

```
<Canvas>
<Rectangle Width="100"
            Height="100"
            Fill="Aqua"
            Canvas.Left="100"
            Canvas.Top="100" />
</Canvas>
```